# Show positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $M_1 \succ 0$, $M_1-M_2^{T}M_3^{-1}M_2 \succ 0$ and $M_2\neq 0$, can we show $M_3 \succ 0$?

If the answer is no, then can we put some constraints on $M_2$ in order to make $M_3 \succ 0$?

Comment: $M_1 = 10, M_2 = 1, M_3 = -1$ says no.